# Erlang error message : global' at node 'X' requested disconnect from node 'Y' in order to prevent overlapping partition. Why?

Tags: networking, erlang, nodes, erlang-otp

I have 135 nodes distributed over 8 CPUs. After upgrading to OTP25 , Erlang updated kernel's env variable to {prevent_overlapping_partitions,true} which is ok.
I do start properly all the nodes as I did before the OTP25 upgrade but I get this error :

global' at node 'X' requested disconnect from node 'Y' in order to prevent overlapping

What can cause the nodes to disconnect now when they were not disconnecting before the update? What can I do to solve this?

Thank you.

In order to solve the problem I created a node monitoring routine that registers the nodes and uses net_kernel to restart a node if disconnecting. I made also sure that all the nodes were restarted so that I get a "clean" starting point. At some point "out of nowhere" the errors start popping and the nodes start to disconnect which it did not happen before.